# Added HTML meta "robots" directive to "noindex", Google still shows my website in search results

Tags: googlebot, noindex

I want Google to not show my website in search results (since its for internal users spread across the globe). As documented at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag, I have included the meta "robots" directive "noindex" in all the pages of my website. Its been almost a week, still I see my website in Google search results. I am sure I have most probably not grasped what it takes to take my website off Google, would someone be able to enlighten me please. I have tried to find my answers on Google, but haven't been able to find an authorative answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for it to take some time for search engines like Google to re-crawl and re-index your website after you make changes to the content or structure. This process can take several days or even weeks, depending on the size and complexity of your website and the workload of the search engine's crawlers.

If you have included the "noindex" directive in the meta tags of all the pages on your website and you are still seeing your website in Google search results after a week, there are a few things you can check:

1. Make sure that the meta tags are placed in the head section of your HTML code and that they are correctly formatted.
2. Check that your website is not being blocked by any other meta tags or directives, such as "noarchive" or "nosnippet." These directives can prevent Google from showing your website in search results, but they may also have unintended consequences, such as preventing Google from caching your pages.
3. Make sure that you have not included any meta tags or directives that contradict the "noindex" directive, such as "index" or "follow." These directives may override the "noindex" directive and allow Google to continue showing your website in search results.
4. Check that your website is not being blocked by any other means, such as robots.txt or a password-protected

Comment: Thanks! I logged in to Google search console, noticed that page wasn't crawled after meta tags were added. I raised a request in console for removals and voila it was gone the next day!